# showing progress indicator while scenekit is loading scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, scenekit

I am struggling to create a progress indicator which will show how much a an SCNScene is loading.
I tried to use the SCNSceneScource class to get a status handler as described by apple's documentation. However, this only gets me so far as to tell me when the scene has loaded. Yet this is not the information I wanted - I would like to show the total progress including the loading time AND the time needed until the SCNNode is displayed ( I assume that is the time needed to push the loaded file into the graphic adapter's memory).

My approach only shows the first of the two times. I did the following: I added an SCNView outlet (self.skView) a button who triggers loading the scene and a UIProgressBar to my View. The progress bar is reflecting the SCNSceneSource's totalProgress property.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // set up the SCNView
        if (_skView.scene==nil) _skView.scene = [SCNScene new];
}

-(void) loadScene {
        SCNSceneSource *s = [SCNSceneSource sceneSourceWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Muscles_V04" withExtension:@"dae"] options:nil];
        SCNScene *scene = [s sceneWithOptions:nil statusHandler:^(float totalProgress, SCNSceneSourceStatus status, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        self.proressBar.progress = totalProgress;
        NSLog(@"Total progress %.3f",totalProgress);

        // once finished remove the status indicator
        if (totalProgress>=0.9999) {
                [self.proressBar removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }];

        // add the nodes of the loaded scene to the existing scene
        for (SCNNode *n in scene.rootNode.childNodes) {
            NSLog(@"node: %@", n.name);
            [self.skView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:n];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to mention that loading your DAE file and adding the child nodes to the scene at runtime isn't optimal.

All the stuff you're doing in your `-loadScene` method could be done in an auxiliary program, before you compile your iOS program. Build the scene programmatically. Archive it using `NSCoding`. Embed that scene file in your iOS app. Load the archive at runtime.

For better performance, you could (in your auxiliary program that creates the scene archive) flatten the nodes, create some `SCNLevelOfDetail` instances, bake in lighting. In your live app, you could call `prepareObjects:withCompletionHandler` in the background, and hopefully see enough of a speedup that using `prepareObject:shouldAbortBlock:`/NSProgress isn't necessary.